# What is the syntax of Spring Boot "application.properties" file?

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I've seen different delimeters for properties
: =
Can't find reference about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `application.properties` you can specify properties in either of these forms:

- Using `=`:

  > key=value
- Using `:`

  > key: value

All examples in the Spring docs for `application.properties` use `=` as the delimiter. But Java properties also supports `:` so by extension Spring (which is utilising `java.util.Properties` under the hood also supports `:`. Here's the relevant extract from the `java.util.Properties` Javadoc ...

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator.